# Сумма из трех Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Есть 3 разных модели (для условности пусть называются `EOne`, `ETwo`, `EThree`) и 1 главная модель `Organization`. В каждой из 3 доп. моделей есть поля `paymentSum` и `organization_id`. Нужно сформировать такой запрос в репозитории, чтобы на каждую `Organization` возвращалась сумма всех трех моделей из сумм `paymentSum`.

Пример структуры:

`Organization`

[image: Organization]

`E1`

[image: E1]

`E2`

[image: E2]

`E3`

[image: E3]

Исходя из этих данных запрос должен вернуть что-то вроде:

[image: Результат]

Т.е. нужно как-то проссумировать суммы в трех таблицах для каждой `Organization`. Как это правильно сделать в рамках Symfony?

Для примера вот еще похожий запрос, почти как надо работающий на SQL:

> select o.id, o.title, ((select sum(a.payment_sum) from appointment a
> where a.organization_id = o.id and a.service_at >= '2023-02-01' and
> a.status IN(1, 6)) + (select sum(ae.payment_sum) from analysis_entry
> ae where ae.organization_id = o.id and ae.service_at >= '2023-02-01'
> and ae.status IN(2, 7)) + (select sum(rr.payment_summ) from
> reanimobile_request rr where rr.organization_id = o.id and
> rr.resuscitation_at >= '2023-02-01' and rr.status in(2))) totalSum
> from organization o;

Т.е., как видно для таблиц с агрегацией также используются доп. фильтры (+ нужно будет ограничить пагинацией). Единственное, что, здесь возвращаются организации с пустым totalSum, а их тоже нужно исключить.

Можно ли мой кейс решить полностью или частично на Symfony, в крайнем случае составить какой-то корректный SQL?

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` - в данную функцию вы передаете значение `paymentSum`, если оно = null, функция выберет следующий аргумент, т.е. 0 и далее, через услорвие `having` выбираем организации, у которых `totalSum` больше 0.

```
/**
 * @param array $organizations
 *
 * @return Organization[]
 */
public function getTotalSumByOrganizations(array $organizations): array
{
    /**
     * result : [
     *     [
     *         "organizationId" => 1,
     *         "organizationTitle" => "Foo",
     *         "totalSum" => 1234567
     *     ],
     *     [
     *         "organizationId" => 2,
     *         "organizationTitle" => "Bar",
     *         "totalSum" => 1234
     *     ],
     *     ...
     * ]
     *
     * @var QueryBuilder $qb
     */
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
    return $qb
        ->leftJoin('o.EOne', 'eone')
        ->leftJoin('o.ETwo', 'etwo')
        ->leftJoin('o.EThree', 'ethree')
        ->select('o.id')
        ->select('o.title')
        ->select('(COALESCE(eone.paymentSum, 0) + COALESCE(etwo.paymentSum, 0) + COALESCE(ethree.paymentSum, 0)) as totalSum')
        ->andWhere(
            $qb
                ->expr()
                ->in(
                    'o.id',
                    array_map(
                        static function(Organization $organization) {
                            return $organization->getId();
                        },
                        $organizations
                    )
                )
        )
        ->groupBy('o.id, o.title')
        ->having('totalSum > 0')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```